# Terminate a process from node js

Tags: node.js

//Run commands to start navigation and robot_pose package

```
 nav = spawn("roslaunch",["turtlebot3_navigation", "turtlebot3_navigation.launch","map_file:=$HOME/catkin_ws/src/robot-rosbridge/server/newmap.yaml"], { shell: true })
 nav.stdout.on("data", data => {
     console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
 });
 nav.on('error', (error) => {
     console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
     res.sendStatus(500)
 });
```

Well here I'm trying to terminate the nav process using "nav.kill()" but the process is not terminating .Earlier while I was using spawn without { shell: true } nav.kill() worked fine but now its not working.

On the whole I'm trying to spawn a process when a specific route is requested and terminate it when another route is requested

i.e.,

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get("/start", (req, res) => {
    //spawn a process
});

app.get("/stop", (req, res) => {
    //kill process
});
```

I'm confused as to how spawn is working. Can anyone suggest a solution and the working of the spawn function or any better alternative.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using a different signal (`nav.kill('SIGKILL')`).

Comment: If you're confused about how spawn is working, I suggest you read the node documentation about it, which is very useful. There is even a part about killing the process : https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#subprocesskillsignal

Comment: Thanks for the response @robertklep but still not working :-(